# Change position of ZoomControls

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on a project related with Maps. The problem stands that the MapControls are positioned in right bottom. That position get covered with something else. So i want to remove the controls from there and place them somewhere else. I don't want to use custom positioning. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `ZoomControls`

```
<ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomcontrols"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and you can set onclicklistener to that.

```
zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrols);
    zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomIn();
        }
    });
    zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapController.zoomOut();
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's the point. I don't want to create other Controls. I want to use Map ones. But I just need to change their position.

Comment: I don't think you can customize that. If you got it anyway, Please post the answer. I wish to check how people do that. :-)